# Backpack Permissionmanager not getting install

Tags: permissions, laravel-backpack

I am using Laravel Backpack and trying to setup roles and permissions in it.
Command I am using is:

```
composer require backpack/permissionmanager
```

It is throwing this error again and again:

[image]

Can anyone know why is it so? What else I could do to get it installed?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is NOT installing `backpack/permissionmanager`, but in installing `backpack/devtools`. That is a *private* package, where you only have access to the `dist`, not the `source`.

In short, using Composer you can install things:

- (A) from `dist` - will unzip the package to your `vendor` directory;
- (B) from `source` - will `git clone` the package to your `vendor` directory;

It looks like you're trying to do a `git clone` for `backpack/devtools`, but since you do not have access the `source`, you can't do that.

If you've run the composer command using the `--prefer-source` flag, don't. Otherwise, check your `composer.json` file for any mentions of this preference. You should make sure you're downloading from `dist`, not `source`.